# Using Gmail to read PST files

Tags: outlook, gmail

I have some PST files but do not have Outlook. Can I import the email messages into Gmail? I tried using the Google Apps migration tool, but upon installation it was looking for a valid copy of Outlook. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

- Use the [Office 2010 60 day trial](http://www1.buyoffice.microsoft.com/usa/product.aspx?family=o14_officehb_try&country_id=US&WT.mc_id=ODC_enUS_HomeBusiness_Try&WT.mc_id=ODC_ENUS_OATTryHome_MonTry)
- Setup [IMAP access to Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1668960&page=ts.cs&from=12103&rd=1) in Outlook
- Import your PST into Outlook
- Then once you have both sitting side-by-side in Outlook, cut and paste the email from your PST account into your Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Apps Migration Tool for Microsoft Outlook.**

Although Outlook is in the name of the tool, I'm almost 100% sure it *does not require Outlook to be installed*. You basically download Google's tool here:

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration

and login with your Gmail credentials. Then you select migrate data from PST file.

Just used this for 25 of my users at work when we switched from Exchange to Google Apps for Business. I'm pretty sure it will work for standard Gmail users but if it doesnt I would go with the answer to install a free trial and setup IMAP. Good Luck!

Comment: According to the link, it requires Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

This article describes a solution.

http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/01/moving-pst-files-into-gmail-you-can-try-this-at-home/34209/

Basically, create an imap account to Gmail in outlook, open your pst files in outlook and then move them into the gmail account thru outlook. This gives you access to your pst files' emails in gmail. And it becomes searchable thru Gmail's web portal.

Comment: The OP is asking about answers that don't require Outlook.

Comment: So once you have moved the the emails in the pst to gmail using Outlook you wouldn't need Outlook to view the emails anymore. This can be achieved using a trial version of office if license purchase is the issue.